# Animations blinks when hovered

Tags: css, css-animations

I created a simple animation where an array of words roll one after the other in an infinite loop.

```js
function App() {
  const words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word1'];

  return (
    <div className="container-container">
  sometime, "word1" blinks for no apparent reason (hover on it if it doesn't happen)
      <div className="container-rollingText">
        {words.map((word) => {
          return <div className="singleWord"> {word} </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container-rollingText {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 140px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.singleWord {
  font-size: 65px;
  animation: roll-up 8s infinite;

  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes roll-up {
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-300%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-400%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-500%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pk2xui?file=App.tsx,style.css

It works fine, except that sometime, it blinks once when the animation starts a new loop.

It feels random, and I can't figure out a cause. It seems to happen when I hover on the div containing the rolling words, though there is no hover effect built in my code.

Could someone guide me on what provokes this blink, and maybe suggest a solution?

Comment: If you replace the last `word1` with `qwerty` you will understand why it blinks.

Comment: thanks for helping. I still don't understand why it wouldn't work, or more specifically: why it blinks only when I hover

Comment: Web pages are single threaded, so having too much going on at the same time can create glitches. You got six animations, and there is possibly (I'm guessing) some extra calculation that happens when you hover an element. One solution is to just animate one container, another solution to just use two elements that slide, and change the bottom content every time.

Comment: I reduced the number of animation as suggested - it works fine now. Thanks!